# Extension methods on a poco class in subsonic?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, subsonic, subsonic3

I'm considering switching from fluent nhibernate to subsonic as nhib just seems to have a MASSIVE memory footprint which I'm really not enjoying, but I just want to check how subsonic (the simple repository probably) would cope with:

- adding extra fields to a database: at the moment I can map a dictionary value to a field in the database which is VERY cool, is this possible in subsonic? (or anything similar?)

  FWIW: DynamicComponent(x => x.PropertyBag, GetDynamicComponentPart); where propertybag is a Dictionary.
- many to many relationships
- cascading saves/deletes
- mapping a complex object to an xml or varchar(max) column (seralize it to xml obviously)

Comment: 30 min?  Your title does not reflect your question at all.

Comment: I was jking sorry. My post sort of expanded somewhat from the title, can't think of a better one though

Comment: NHibernate doesn't inherently use a lot of memory.  Are you sure you are using it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> * adding extra fields to a database: at the moment I can map a
> ```
>
> dictionary value to a field in the
>   database which is VERY cool, is this
>   possible in subsonic? (or anything
>   similar?)
>
> ```
>   FWIW: DynamicComponent(x => x.PropertyBag,
> ```
>
> GetDynamicComponentPart); where
>   propertybag is a Dictionary.

Adding fields is fairly simple.  Just add the field to the table, then re-generate the classes from the T4 template.

You won't get any mapping beyond basic primitive types, though.  Certainly not a dictionary in a field.

> ```
> * many to many relationships
> ```

You will have to make custom modifications to the T4 template to get any sort of support for many-to-many tables.  SubSonic just treats them like any other table.

I have made such modifications and they are of limited usefulness.

> ```
> * cascading saves/deletes
> ```

Only on the RDBMS side.  That is, if you setup foreign key relationships with cascades.  SubSonic doesn't do any of this.

> ```
> * mapping a complex object to an xml or varchar(max) column (seralize
> ```
>
> it to xml obviously)

Nope.  You get no support like this.  There are no extensibility hooks to insert your own type converters.

SubSonic is a completely different field from NHibernate.  I would call NHib an ORM, but I would not call SubSonic that.  Rob Conery, the author of SubSonic, would call it a query tool.

It is very simplistic, which is its goal and strength (as well as weakness).  It assists with querying and modifications in a strongly typed way.  It lacks a huge amount of features and configurability/extensibility compared to NHib or even Entity Framework.

I would caution against moving from NHib to SS, especially if you have any amount of functionality implemented in NHibernate already.  Not that SS is a bad tool, but it has a lot of restrictions.

Comment: Ok thanks - looks like SS isn't right for me - better work out why nhib eats quite the amount of memory that it does and there's a way of minimising it. Ta!